# IT Certification to cover basic IT skills

Tags: recruitment, skills, technical-interviews, assessment

Which well known IT certifications will cover the following (or get close to it)?

We need to extend our recruitment process with a technical assessment of the candidate, and would like to pass them on to a test which confirms their capabilities, rather than assessing candidate-by-candidate.

```
Basic Web Development (html/css/js)
Basic Databases (SQL)
Basic Networking
Basic Cloud
Basic CLI (Win/Linux)
Basic Integration (SOAP/REST/API)
Basic Architecture (patterns/design)
Basic Project/Task management (SCRUM/Kanban)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I easily cover all of it (although a little weak on the *nix side and I hate css and js), and I don't have a single "certification" to show. Why would I, I got an education and work experience.

Comment: Degree and work experience also is a strong indication that they can relatively quickly pick up new skills as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account your previous question, the short answer is you cannot.

If you have requirements, you need to be able to check them. If you cannot come up with simple questions to make sure your candidates are suited to the roles, you need the person in your company that requires those people, to come up with those questions. If they cannot, then you need to take a deep look into a mirror and ask yourself why you require something that you do not understand yourself in the company.

For example if nobody is able to ascertain the level of JS proficiency in a candidate, then who exactly decided you even need people proficient in JS?

How are you sure that the JS skill solves any business problem, if nobody currently working for you even knows what it is or how to properly use it?

There are third party providers of credentials. It's called an "education". Whether that is a college degree or apprenticeship or whatever is available in your country. They are solid. They have exams. They get diplomas.

It is perfectly normal to require one of those.

But if you have specialized requirements, if *you* cannot explain them and check them, then nobody can.

I mean just imagine you found a 20 questions Scrum quizz online and someone scores "14/20" on it. Now what? Is that good enough? How would you know what it means? If those weren't *your* 20 questions, with *your* take on what "14/20" means for their future in *your* company, it is pointless.